# TeXLive: added custom .sty .cls but I still obtain "not found" error

Tags: texlive, lncs

I am using Fedora 23 operating system with TeXLive version 2014.19.20140525_r34255.fc23

I downloaded [llncs2e.zip](ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/llncs/latex2e/llncs2e.zip) then I unpacked the llncs2e folder content inside

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/llncs2e
```

but it seems to not work. Here the full TeX test document

```
\documentstyle{llncs}
%
\begin{document}

\title{TEST TITLE}

\author{Foo}

\institute{Foo}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

Foo

\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

Foo

\end{document}
```

I also tried to add on top

```
\usepackage{llncs}
```

[More infos about the package](https://www.springer.com/computer/lncs?SGWID=0-164-6-793341-0)

Comment: ***Don't*** add custom packages or classes in `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist`, but in the tree you get as output from `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL`

Answer (score 0):

kaste_ #latex Freenode user told me to run

```
# texhash
```

and now everything works fine